# laravel manipulation array without for loop for better performance and optimization

Tags: laravel, loops, optimization, eloquent

I have one JSON like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "order_id": 1,
    "product_id": 2,
    "quantity": "15.00",
    "created_at": "2019-03-19 10:02:40",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "24 mantra",
        "sale_price": "45.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "order_id": 2,
    "product_id": 2,
    "quantity": "15.00",
    "created_at": "2019-03-19 10:16:15",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "24 mantra",
        "sale_price": "45.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "order_id": 3,
    "product_id": 2,
    "quantity": "15.00",
    "created_at": "2019-03-19 10:16:19",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "24 mantra",
        "sale_price": "45.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "order_id": 1,
    "product_id": 3,
    "quantity": "3.00",
    "created_at": "2019-03-19 10:02:40",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "24 Mantra Jowar Atta 2LB",
        "sale_price": "45.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "order_id": 2,
    "product_id": 3,
    "quantity": "3.00",
    "created_at": "2019-03-19 10:16:16",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "24 Mantra Jowar Atta 2LB",
        "sale_price": "45.00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

now I want to calculate total sale as quantity multiply by product of `sale_price` of every object and sum of `quantity * sale_price` per product.

**expected output**

```
[
  {
   "product": "24 mantra",
   "sale": 2025
  },
  {
   "product": "24 Mantra Jowar Atta 2LB",
   "sale": 270
  }
 ]
```

**code for output**

```
  $orderlines = OrderLine->with('products:id,name,sale_price')->select('id','order_id','product_id','quantity','created_at')->get();
  $orderlines = $orderlines->groupBy('product_id');
  $totalproductsale = [];

  foreach($orderlines as $key => $singleline) {
    $total_bysales = 0.00;
        foreach($singleline as $singleproduct) {
          $total_bysales += $singleproduct->quantity * $singleproduct->sale_price;
        }
   array_push($totalproductsale,array("product" => $singleline['0']->products['0']->name,"totalsale" => number_format($total_bysales, 2, '.', '')));
   $totalsale[$key] = number_format($total_bysales, 2, '.', '');
      }
```

I want to get total sale and product name into one object, for that I have used a `foreach` loop but it's very time consuming, I have 100 000 data into production server. It takes 15 sec to load only 30k data into chart. how can I reduce the time of iteration or use any other alternatives?

Comment: How long does the `$orderlines = (...)->get` thing take? Is it an SQL query? An API call? How slow/fast is it?

Comment: It's eloquent model query....i want to send data to front-end side. I have used angular as front-end

Comment: OK but how do you know the loop takes 15 seconds and not that query?

Comment: i don't know which one takes longer time but when inspect from network it shows 15 sec to get response.

Comment: People outside SE asia will be confused about what is "lac data". So please standard measurements

Answer (score 0):

Convert array in a collection with the `collect` helper and do operations on that. There are a lot of helper functions to achieve what you are trying to, with few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, the json you must take it to the controller. I pasted the json directly

```
$json = '[ { "id": 1, "order_id": 1, "product_id": 2, ... ]';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$collection = collect($array);
```

Then you can manipulate the data easily with a collection

[image]